# Azure service startup logs

Tags: c#, azure, asp.net-core

I have asp.net core 2.2 application running on azure service. 
It was working fine before but now when I deploy it I get this error: `An error occurred while starting the application.` I don't see anything in application log files because this happens before application starts. 
So, my question is, is there any azure log file which I can take look at to see what is causing the error?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Many startup errors will not see any useful information in the log. At this time you can use the kudu tool (this is the method provided by MS, this is the [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/test/troubleshoot-azure-iis?view=aspnetcore-2.2#run-the-app-in-the-kudu-console-1)), which is located under the Under Development Tools / Advanced Tools.

How to use kudu tools:

> Open Kudo
>
> Go to DEBUG CONSOLE (Top Menu), then CMD
>
> CD site
>
> CD wwwroot
>
> DIR to list contents. Find your dll in the list to ensure you are in
>   the right location.
>
> DOTNET your.dll

For more information about how to use the kudu tools, have a look of this doc:

https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/36467.understanding-the-azure-app-service-editor.aspx